# In a query, how do I convert nvarchar that is formatted as hh:mmAM[PM] to time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to query a table with records that have a start_time and end_time field. Their data type is **nvarchar(100)** and formatted like this example: 09:30AM

I need to do a before or after comparison on these fields, and to do so I need them in the **time** data format. (Correct me if I am mistaken).
In the query, how do I convert the start_time and end_time so I can do my comparison?

NOTE: I have tried *convert(time, start_time)*, but get a *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string* error message.

Comment: Converting to time with your example works just fine. select convert(time, '09:30AM'). This most likely means you have some bad data in there somewhere....a solid example of why it is so critical to use the proper datatypes.

Comment: Aside: Using a [persisted computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql) may be helpful. Of course, using the correct datatype is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, '09:30AM')
```

OR

```
CAST('09:30AM' as time)
```

If the converision failed that mean you have some bad data somewhere, I would recommand the [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) if you have 2012+ which return `NULL` in case the coverison failed

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(TIME, '09:30AMBadDataHere')
```